# (T)retObject[parameter] Cannot unbox 'retObject[parameter]' as a 'T'

Tags: c#, generics, wmi

Not much to say,
This is the issue:

```
    public static T WriteIfNotNull<T>(ManagementObject retObject, string parameter)
    {
        return retObject[parameter] != null ? (T)retObject[parameter] : default(T);
    }
```

It breaks when `T` is an `int` and `retObject[parameter]` is an object. The odd part (for me at least) is that if `T` is not `T` and is actually a specified int it does work.

It says it can't be casted to `T` (even that in this case `T` is `int`).

@Edit: @dtb here it goes:

```
Specified cast is not valid. 
(T)(object)retObject[parameter] Cannot unbox 'retObject[parameter]' as a 'T'    int
```

And the values:

parameter: `"ProcessId"`

retObject[parameter]: `4`

default(T): `0`

@@Edit: Here's the call too

```
pr.ProcessId = Util.WriteIfNotNull<int>(retObject, "ProcessId");
```

Comment: (Sorry but no... the problem is the T, not the object. =(
It still throws that error.)

Comment: Please add the full error message.

Comment: When you say "breaks" are you talking compile or runtime?

Comment: At Runtime I recently added the values

Comment: And what is the *type* of retObject[parameter], are you sure it's `int` and not `short`, `long`, etc?

Comment: Yes, what's `retObject[parameter].GetType().Name`? If it's not the same as `T` -- tough.

Comment: You cannot unbox an `short` or `long` as an `int` for example...

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info: there I added the call.

Comment: that's the type of `T`, what is the actual type of the object stored in `retObject[parameter]`?  Jon's code would show it to you.

Comment: @Jon is Unsigned... `retObject[parameter].GetType().Name "UInt32"`
What should I do? if I say `Util.WriteIfNotNull<UInt32>(retObject, "ProcessId");` the insert on the database (SQL) That I have to do won't work. I need to do the cast.
And as UInt32 It will bring also UInt64 (*Which I cast later to bigint*) and UInt16

Comment: See my answer below, you can do a conversion, but not a cast in this situation.  If you want it to go to `int` you must convert it to `int`.  You *could* cast to `uint` and then cast to `int` which would correctly unbox and then convert, but that doesn't work well in a generic context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that what's happening is that `retObject[parameter]` isn't actually an `int` but is another numeric type (`uint` for process IDs typically), in which case you'd want to use `Convert` to actually change the value:

```
return retObject[parameter] != null 
    ? (T)Convert.ChangeType(retObject[parameter], typeof(T)) 
    : default(T);
```

The reason a simple cast doesn't work here is because casting from `object` to `int` only works if it's actually a boxed `int`.  You can't do a downcast and conversion cast in one operation because there is not a conversion cast from `object` to `int`.  Thus casting away from `object` requires you to cast to the exact type or a valid super-type, interface, etc of the exact type.

So, to convert a boxed `uint` to an `int` we'd have to either unbox as an `int` first (problematic) or use one of the `Convert` methods to change the type (as shown above).

`Convert.ChangeType()` works for converting between compatible types even if they are boxed.  For example, if `retObject[parameter]` returns a `long` then this will allow it to be converted to a `T` of `int`.

I have a blog post on this [here](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2011/01/27/c.net-little-pitfalls-the-dangers-of-casting-boxed-values.aspx) with more detail, hopefully this makes sense.  The gist, again, is that casting from `object` is a downcast (no conversion casts are defined for `object`) thus you must cast it to it's precise type (or a valid sub-type).

Comment: Yes, nearly anything that implements `IConvertible` can be used with `Convert.ChangeType()`, thus: `int x = (int)Convert.ChangeType("13", typeof(int));` works...

Comment: In fact, you can constrain your generic `where T : IConvertible` if you want to enforce that only convertible types can use this method...

Comment: Excellent, I'm implementing this